# Minimizing memory overhead using C++ containers (std::map and std::vector too expensive)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, dictionary, stl

I am expecting to be handling a huge number of data records, whereby around 20 `uint8_t` keys will have millions of `<int, struct>` pairs associated with each of them (ordered by `int`). These pairs are rather lightweight at ~10 bytes, and need to be allocated dynamically.

Initially, I was using a `std::map<uint8_t, std::vector<int, struct>>` but after studying the overhead associated with vectors, namely the `capacity()` in

> 3 machine words in total + `sizeof(element)` * `capacity()`

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11841458/1487804); `capacity()` "typically has room for up to twice the actual number of elements" which is seemingly detrimental.

Instead of a vector, I could use a std::map, however the overhead of [~32 bytes per node](http://info.prelert.com/blog/stl-container-memory-usage) also becomes very expensive for such light weight pairs.

I am unfamiliar with Boost and other C++ libraries, so was wondering whether anyone could advise on a solution where I could avoid manual dynamic memory allocation?

---

**Edit :** To clarify following a few questions in comments, the struct stored will contain 3 shorts (to start with), and no further data structures. I anticipate the length of the `vector` to be no greater than 1.5*10^8, and understand this comes to ~1.4 GiB (thanks @dyp).

I suppose the question is rather, how to manage vector `capacity()` such that reallocation through `reserve()` is kept to a minimum. I am also unsure of the efficiency of `shrink_to_fit()` (C++11)

Comment: What is in struct? What is the typical size of vector? Does it have a maximum? Is it known at compile-time?

Comment: You can well adapt the initial capacity of `std::vector`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Isn't that only a suggestion of *at least* this number of elements?

Comment: You can roll out a "flat map" which is `std::vector<std::pair<key, value>>` and by sorting the vector before operations, you can use `std::lower_bound` and similar functions to perform binary search. There may be a premade such structure in boost.

Comment: *Millions of pairs of 10 bytes* sounds like several dozen megabyte to me. 20 of them can still be of the order of hundreds of megabyte up to some gigabyte. Is this really a problem for the target machine?

Comment: @neil-kirk The struct will contain roughly 3-5 shorts. I expect the vector size to be no greater than 1.5*10^8 elements long (max), however the maximum size could be less and yes I could determine this but not at compile-time. The typical size is unknown at the moment.

Comment: The answer you've quoted is correct, but may be misleading you a bit. He's basically saying that capacity *could* be up to double the current size. That can only happen if the growth factor is at least 2, and even then happens only immediately after reallocation. A more typical case would be a growth factor of 1.5, and the added area around half full, so wasted area of ~25%. I've never seen growth factor greater than 2. Equal to 2 was once common, but 1.5 seems typical in current implementations.

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK So we're talking about a minimum memory consumption (for the worst case) of about 1.5*10^9 byte, i.e. 1.4 GiB?

Comment: What does "roughly" mean? What I wanted to know is if it contains any data structures of its own.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The libstdc++ implementation of `vector` (GCC 4.8.2) actually does double the capacity each time.

Comment: Since the additional reserved elements in a vector are never accessed, they do not require any committed memory (only address space). I expect there'll be no problem in a typical StdLib implementation if you have enough physical memory for the actually used elements (if you reserve and don't use the automatic growth feature).

Comment: If you resize an empty vector to X, typically the compiler will only allocate memory for X and no more. I know this is implementation defined. I tested with VS2013 and ideone.com

Comment: @NeilKirk Sorry for not clarifying. It wont contain any data structures, simply 3 shorts.

Comment: @dyp I think you are off by an order of magnitude. Pidgey, so if we have 10 million elements then minimum memory consumption is approximately 220mb in any case. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @dyp Yes, that is correct. You're right as well regarding the system, it can handle this kind of memory. However as I move forwards I intend to increase this workload, and want to scrutinise the memory performance before stepping up.

Comment: Thinking about this further, the problem cannot be the map, as there are a maximum of 256 keys, which is not many. The huge memory usage must come from the value and not from the map itself.

Comment: Even though map isn't the problem, I would consider using `std::vector<value>`, where the vector is 256 in size, one for each key, and empty keys are just left with an empty value. This will cost a constant amount of approximately 3kb, which is chicken feed, and will have faster lookup.

Comment: @NeilKirk Good point, I will definitely be switching that out.

Comment: What are the ints in the vectors? Are they sequential? Can you do without them after sorting the items per vector? Can any of the other information be thrown away after reading data in, or is the structure truly dynamic?

Comment: @larsmans The ints are offsets, sequential yet not uniform in any way (well, from what I expect). As Neil suggested, I can discard the uint8_t keys however the <int, struct> pairs will be allocated dynamically (they are derived from input data). So far, I expect to be using `vector<vector<pair<int, struct>>>`, and will need to simply consider best ways to avoid the 2x capacity(), as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @NielKirk's point about std::vector<> instead of a map for the keys, with only 256 possibilities you could also consider std::array<> (or even a C-style array) for the keys.

As for the std::pair<int, struct> elements, an initial implementation had them as members of a std::vector<std::pair<int, struct>> collection, and you said

> *Instead of a vector, I could use a std::map, however the overhead of ~32 bytes per node also becomes very expensive for such light weight pairs.*

which implies the `int` part of the element is unique as you did not mention std::multimap.  You could take a look at Google `sparsehash` (http://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/).  From the project home page:

> An extremely memory-efficient hash_map implementation. 2 bits/entry overhead! The SparseHash library contains several hash-map implementations, including implementations that optimize for space or speed.
>
> These hashtable implementations are similar in API to SGI's hash_map class and the tr1 unordered_map class, but with different performance characteristics. It's easy to replace hash_map or unordered_map by sparse_hash_map or dense_hash_map in C++ code.

I've used it before, and never had a problem with it.  Your `uint8_t` keys could index into a (std::vector/std::array/C-array) collection *KCH* of hashmaps.  If you wanted to you could even define *KCH* as collection of objects, each containing a hashmap, so each *KCH[i]* can implement a convenient interface for working with `std::pair<int, struct>` objects for that key.  You'd have a "bad key" element as a default for non-key elements in the collection referencing either a) a single empty dummy hashmap or b) a "bad key object" that handles an unexpected key value appropriately.

Something like this:

```cxx
typedef std::pair<int, struct>                            myPair;
typedef google::sparse_hash_map<int, myPair>              myCollectionType;
typedef google::sparse_hash_map<int, myPair>::iterator    myCollectionIter;

myCollectionType dummyHashMap;
std:array<myCollectionType, 256> keyedArray;
```

Initialize all `keyedArray` elements to `dummyHashMap`, then fill in with different hash maps for valid keys.

Similarly, with containing objects:

```
class KeyedCollectionHandler {
public:
    virtual bool whatever(parm);
    ...

private:
    myCollectionType collection;
};

class BadKeyHandler : public KeyedCollectionHandler 
{
public:
    virtual bool whatever(parm){
        // unknown or unexpected key, handle appropriately
    }
    ...
};

BadKeyHandler badKeyHandler;
```

Initialize 256 keyed array elements to `badKeyHandler`, fill in `KeyedCollectionHandler` objects for good key values.

Comment: Who is this person called Niel Kirk?

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant and thorough answer - `sparsehash` seems to fit the bill. Did you compare the performance of `sparsehash`with the supposedly more efficient `dense` implementation?

Comment: Thank you for the gracious response.  No, I did not compare sparse_ to dense_hash_map for performance.  For our needs, space considerations were not an issue, it was performance.  For what we needed, dense_hash_map just crushed std::map for performance.  I would expect the sparse_ implementation to impress as well.

Comment: This page might also be helpful - it's got a link to some performance numbers as well as the implementation details: http://sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html

Comment: @frasnian That link is brilliant - thanks. It's re-assuring to see how similar the map_fetch times are, now just to benchmark my growth performance...