# Which vector and map, uses less memory (large set of data and unknown size)

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap, large-data

I wonder which container uses less memory between `std::map` and `std::vector` with a large set of data.

Loads of posts talk about efficiency, and my priority is not efficiency but memory consumption. So, if we don't know the number of our data (in my case can be over 12,000,000 entries, every entry is a string of 20 characters), is map really better than vector?

Comment: `map` and `vector` do different things: `map` stores key-value pairs, not single values. Typically, associative containers have more overhead since they store pointers alongside the data and allocate each node individually; but `vector` needs contiguous memory, and might cause fragmentation if you let it reallocate too often. The only real answer is to measure.

Comment: Vector contains a contiguous array, so it takes exactly `size() * sizeof(value_type)` bytes of dynamic storage. Map has one dynamic node per entry, which adds fair amount of overhead.

Comment: I'd consider rolling my own here - with 12 million entries you could justify it - how much memory are you trying to save?  A container for 12 million sets of 20 characters is likely to be better than a container for 12 million containers of 20 characters (aka strings).  For that matter, 20 character strings of [a-z] have the order of 10^28 possible values, in which case representing each string as a 96 bit integer is a possibility?  How weird are you prepared to get?

Comment: You can take a look at http://info.prelert.com/blog/stl-container-memory-usage and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841357/memory-consumption-by-stl-containers

Comment: @AndyNewman, I know but for each string, i've got a container of other data. Each string is different.

Comment: If you are worried about getting large enough individual blocks, deque is a strictly better choice than map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the problem you are solving. Basically , the std::vector uses a row memory(as your data is big, make sure you have one), but the std::map can take each node from separate parts of the memory. Opposite, std::map uses more memory for the same data because the pointer manipulation between nodes.

Comment: But at resize, does a vector copy all his data in another contiguous memory row? Or does it keep two rows?

Comment: if your vectors size is n, and you call resize(m) there m > n , it just adds the necessary m-n part to your vector, if m < n , it just deletes the remaining n-m part. So it never keep two rows in case of resize.

Comment: It's not true, if m<n, it doesn't deletes the remaining part. In C++11, there is shrink_to_fit that does it, but not with resize.

Comment: @Atouk, resizing a vector to a smaller size deletes content. Making the vector larger adds elements to the end as long as the capacity is not reached. In that case it is reallocated and moved to a new memory-area: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

Answer (score 3):

A `std::vector` *must* organise the strings in contiguous memory. (The standard insists on that). So the amount of contiguous memory in your example will be at least `sizeof(string) * 12,000,000` for a `std::vector`. Fortunately, each string probably has its buffer in the heap: 20 characters is around the cut-off for `std::string` implementations that use a fixed buffer for short strings.

`std::map` will not have this contiguity issue, so is probably a better container to use in this instance. But, overall, it will probably consume more memory. But that memory will be easier for the program to acquire.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific sizes you note, you might want to consider something that does not go to either of the extremes: not a continuous array of memory, and not a single-node based tree.

Some options are

- a (memory residing) [B tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)
- a digital tree

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep data in continuous memory you should go for `std::vector` else if you prefer node based data structure  and need to a lot of insert and delete operations I will suggest either `std::list`  instead `std::map`.

If you prefer node based data structure with keeping order between elements of data structure and don't have a key value pair I prefer `std::set` instead `std::map`.

If you prefer node based data structure with data as a key value pair and keeping order between elements depends of key value of data I prefer `std::map`