# std::vector move reverse iterator at end

Tags: c++, iterator

I have this situation:

```
for(auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); ++it)
{
    if(condition(it))
    {
        //Move it at end;
        break;
    }
}
```

What is the most efficient/elegant way to move `*it` at the end of `vec`?

EDIT: `*it`, not `it`

EDIT1: Now I use:

```
auto val = *it; 
vec.erase((++it).base());
vec.push_back(val);
```

But I don't think is very efficient...

Comment: Why? You are breaking out of the loop, and `it` will go out of scope anyway.

Comment: Do you want to move `*it` to the end?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I'll edit the question

Comment: So what do you mean: _swap_ `*it` with `vec.last()`, or "remove it" so that every element after it goes one place further to the front and then append the element, or what?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't want swap, I want the to have the order preserved for the other elements, but to have my element at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To move it to the end:**

```
for(auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); ++it)
{
    if(condition(it))
    {
        auto val = *it;
        vec.erase((++it).base());
        vec.push_back(val);
        break;
    }
}
```

**To swap with the last element:**

```
for(auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); ++it)
{
    if(condition(it))
    {
        auto it2 = --vec.end();
        auto val = *it;
        *it = *it2;
        *it2 = val;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And if `it` becomes invalidated by the call to `push_back`?

Comment: Not really, because the same conditions that would cause `it` to become invalidated would cause `val` to become invalidated.

Comment: Yes, it will compile.  It will give you a reference to the thing that `it` points to.

Comment: @Dukeling it is reverse iterator and erase works on iterators. The code is something like: auto val = *it; vec.erase((++it).base()); vec.push_back(val); but I don't think is very efficient

Comment: @Felics Why `vec.erase((++it).base());` not `vec.erase(it.base());`? I doubt it can be more efficient. To remove it from it's current position will take as long as `erase` takes and `push_back` takes constant time.

Comment: @Dukeling Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator Please correct the erase(it) to be able to accept your answer

Comment: @Felics Thanks, a split-second look at the picture in the link and it all made sense. Corrected.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I see you deleted your answer. I think it was still useful for reference sake.

Answer (score 1):

If prefer standard algorithms over manual loops. So I'd use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

If you need to preserve the order of the elements, moving to the end can be done using [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
auto rit = std::find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [](int i){ return i == 6; });
if (rit != vec.rend()) {
    auto it = rit.base();
    std::rotate(it-1, it, vec.end());
}
```

If you don't need to keep the order, you can use [std::iter_swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap):

```
auto it = std::find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [](int i){ return i == 6; });
if (it != vec.rend())
    std::iter_swap(it, vec.rbegin());
```

[Demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Jflnn%242)