# moving elements in a vector is not working as expected

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++11

I'm trying to move each element that has x value to the beginning of vector so that all the element that has x value is at the front of the vector, but it is not working , so can you tell me what I've done wrong, please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void move_x(Container& c, Arg x)
{
    typename Container::iterator it = find(c.begin(), c.end(), x);
    if (it!=c.end()) {
        c.insert(c.begin(), *it);
       remove (it, c.end(), x);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int x=1;
    vector <int> v{1,2,4,6,7,1,3,1,1,8,9};

    move_x(v, x);
    for(auto i:v)
        cout<<v[i];

    return 0;
}
```

and I'm getting this output when I run it

```
411613848811
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you insert into the container, the iterator is no longer valid

```
    c.insert(c.begin(), *it); // This invalidates 'it'    
    remove (it, c.end(), x); // oops! trying to use invalid iterator
```

Using `std::rotate` provides better alternative, which doesn't invalidate the iterators:

```
template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void move_x(Container& c, Arg x)
{
    typedef typename Container::iterator It;
    It write_it = c.begin(), read_it = c.begin();
    for (;;) {
        It found_it = find(read_it, c.end(), x);
        if (found_it==c.end()) break;
        read_it = found_it;
        ++read_it;
        std::rotate(write_it,found_it,read_it);
        ++write_it;
    }
}
```

As long as you are dealing with simple items like ints, this is a good approach:

```
template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void move_x(Container& c, Arg x)
{
    typename Container::reverse_iterator it = std::remove(c.rbegin(),c.rend(),x);

    for (;it!=c.rend();++it) {
        *it = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fixed implementation, of what you had in your code:

```
template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void move_x(Container& c, Arg x)
{
    typename Container::iterator it = find(c.begin(), c.end(), x);
    if (it!=c.end()) {
       c.erase(it);
       c.insert(c.end(), x);
    }
}
```

One issue with your implementation is that `insert` anywhere [but the end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) can cause a reallocation and regardless will invalidate anything after the inserted position. So by definition since you are inserting at the beginning `it` will not be valid.

The second issue is with `cout<<v[i];` it should actually be `cout<<i;`.

A nicer implementation that uses reverse iterators and moves all `x`s. This one erases as it goes and keeps a `count` and then does `count` inserts when done. Using [erase with reverse iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator) is a little tricky:

```
template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void move_all_x(Container& c, Arg x)
{
    unsigned int count = 0 ;

    for( typename Container::reverse_iterator it = c.rbegin() ; it != c.rend(); )
    {
       if( *it == x )
       {
         c.erase(--(it++).base() ) ;
         ++count ;
       }
       else
       {
          ++it ;
       }
    }

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i )
      {
         c.insert(c.begin(), x) ;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::partition, which will move all elements in a range which meet a given predicate to the beginning of the range, and return an iterator to the first element which doesn't meet the predicate.

```
template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void move_x(Container& c, Arg x)
{
    typename Container::iterator endrange = 
        std::partition(c.begin(), c.end(), [&x](Arg ele){ return ele == x; });
}
```

In this case, we're not using the return value but I think it would probably be useful.

Comment: Neat solution, two issues, you are not capturing `x` and you misplaced the `;` at the end. After I fixed those two it looks like it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. I planned to run this though a compiler but got called away. Seems to compile now.

Answer (score 0):

The output is wrong. There should be `for (auto i:v) cout << i;` not `v[i]`. You would see the garbage with a right algorithm too

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to process all matches (or use count and insert). `v` defined as `list<int>`:

```
template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void move_x(Container& c, Arg x)
{
  for (auto it = find(c.begin(), c.end(), x); 
       it != c.end(); 
       it = find(it, c.end(), x)) {
    c.insert(c.begin(), x); 
    it = c.erase(it);
  }
}
```