# Deleting an element in std::list while iterating in reverse[C++]

Tags: c++, c++11, stdlist

I googled a lot about erasing an element based on some condition while iterating from reverse. `std::reverse_iterator` is good way to re-iterate but it doesn't offer a clean fool proof method to delete an element from what I found by reading.
Any good approach perhaps by using `std::reverse_iterator`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse iterator] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator)

Comment: @Amit You can safely iterate through a container and erase elements out of it along the way.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8d351d22338c5f5