# How to erase a pair<int,int> element in a list

Tags: c++, list, iterator, std-pair

```
list<pair<int,int>> li{{5,6},{7,8},{9,10}};
for(auto it=li.rbegin();it!=li.rend();++it) {
    cout << (*it).first << (*it).second << '\n';
    li.erase(it);
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<std::pair<int, int> >::erase(std::reverse_iterator<std::_List_iterator<std::pair<int, int> > >&)'
>            li.erase(it);

If the `li.erase(it)` is replaced by `li.remove(*it)`, the code works fine. However, all the value will be removed., and the algorithm become O(n<sup>2</sup>), instead of O(n), right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call erase with a reverse iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator)

Answer (score 2):

Erasing while iterating is a bad, bad idea. If `it` is no longer in the list, what will `++it` do? Good question! I don't know, but it's not what you want unless you got unlucky. Why is it unlucky if the program works? Because it doesn't, and next time it might do something completely different.

So pretty much all of the loop-based iterate and delete approaches that seem to work (`li.remove(*it)` and `li.erase( --(it.base()) )` actually don't.

Normally I pitch the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to solve that problem, but the reverse iterator makes this a mess if you try to use C++'s built-in tools. Plus in this case the answer to remove_if is always true.

For the problem posed above, don't even try. Instead, print `li.back()` and then `li.pop_back()` until the list is empty.

```
while (!li.empty()) {
    cout << li.back().first << li.back().second << '\n';
    li.pop_back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `li.erase(it)` with `li.erase(it.base())`.

`std::list.erase` does not allow a `reverse_iterator` as an argument, so you first need to convert the `reverse_iterator` into an `iterator`.

And you're correct, as far as I can tell, about the O(n^2) and O(n) analysis.

**EDIT:**

Actually, according to this similar answer: [How to call erase with a reverse iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator)

What you should really do is `li.erase( --(it.base()) )`