# How to call erase with a reverse iterator using a for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

Regarding the answer provided here: [How to call erase with a reverse iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator/1830240#1830240)

The following results in a segmentation fault (upon `++it`) when compiled in g++ 4.8.4 with -std=c++11. Am I misunderstanding the answer?

```
  std::map<int,int> testmap;
  testmap[0] = 1;
  for(auto it=testmap.rbegin(); it!=testmap.rend(); ++it) {
    testmap.erase( std::next(it).base() );
  }
```

Comment: `it = decltype(it){testmap.erase( std::next(it).base() )};` instead of `++it`.

Comment: Don't you need to use --it with reverse iterator? The answer you cite suggests so.

Comment: @Thinkeye no : reverse iterators traverse forwards through a reversed view of the container. The answer decrements `it.base()` -- the "normal" iterator that corresponds to the reverse iterator.

Comment: @logidelic `erase` invalidates the iterator you pass into it, and returns the one you should continue traversing from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some use of this idiom, I think a modification to the loop in Jarod42's answer is in order to make things safer and maintain the typical `for(;;)` loop niceties:

```
for (auto it = testcont.rbegin(), nit = it; it != testcont.rend(); it = nit) {
    nit = next(it);

    // whatever... maybe a continue somewhere or maybe not

    if (WE_WANT_TO_ERASE(it)) {
        nit = decltype(it){ testcont.erase(std::next(it).base()) };
    }

    // whatever... maybe a continue somewhere or maybe not
}
```

Using the loop in the other answer is too dangerous. If one were to thoughtlessly add a `continue;` somewhere in the loop, without incrementing the iterator first, the result would be an infinite loop. Since, at first glace, this can look like a normal `for(;;)` loop, I believe that this is bound to happen sooner or later. Similarly, if there are branches in the loop, and if one of those branches neglects to increment the iterator, another bug is introduced. Finally, if you do an `erase()`, you need to be *sure* to `continue` before you increment the iterator or else you have yet another bug.

Using the modified loop above, the loop can be treated just like a normal `for(;;)` loop. The trick is to increment `nit` (the "next iterator") as the first line of the loop body. Then you don't have to worry. The only time you need to update `nit` is if you are doing an `erase()`. Everything else works as one would expect a for loop to work.

One final note: I originally asked the question with regard to maps, but this will work correctly for `vector`, `list`, etc, as well.

Answer (score 13):

`erase` invalidates the iterator, so you have to reconstruct it from the return value of `erase`:

```
it = std::map<int,int>::reverse_iterator(testmap.erase( std::next(it).base() ));
```

Or with C++11:

```
it = decltype(it){testmap.erase( std::next(it).base() )};
```

Or with C++17:

```
it = std::reverse_iterator(testmap.erase( std::next(it).base() ));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ce439062830b0c0).

For completeness, here is what the corrected loop from the original question looks like (notice that the iterator increment has been removed from the `for(...)`):

```
for (auto rit = testmap.rbegin(); rit != testmap.rend(); /* empty */) {
    if (WE_WANT_TO_ERASE(rit)) {
        rit = decltype(rit){ testmap.erase(std::next(rit).base()) };
    } else {
        ++rit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to skip `++it` if you `erase`, lest you skip an element.

Comment: Thanks for this response... I believe that you are correct, but I'm surprised that in the other discussions people have suggested (unchallenged) that this is not necessary. (For example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3808880/1072039 )

Comment: Um, doesn't reverse iterator of iterator point to the previous element or somesuch?  (so reverse(end()) and reverse(begin()) form a range)

Comment: @logidelic: in the other question, there is a `break` to end the loop, that may explain why that point has not been really discussed.

Comment: @Yakk: I don't understand your point: `{reverse_iterator(v.end()), reverse_iterator(v.begin())}` is the range`{v.rbegin(), v.rend()}`. (and indeed its internal should point into a *valid* range `{ v.begin(), v.end()}`)

Comment: @Jarod42 Hmm.  I guess it works: `erase` points to the next element after the erased one, and the one before the next element is the next element in reverse iteration.