# string erase appends elements with backward iterators

Tags: c++, string, c++11, iterator

I am trying to remove every `'0'` in a `std::string`, starting from the back. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830240/3980929), there are multiple ways to `.erase` backward iterators.

The weird thing is that they all append numbers to the `std::string`, instead of erasing them!

Here is a little sample

```
//'str' will be "5.090000"
std::string str = std::to_string(5.09);

auto it = std::remove_if(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), [](char value) {
    return value == '0';
});
```

1) Pre-`C++11` way:

```
str.erase(--(it.base()));
```

2) `C++11` way (1)

```
str.erase(std::next(it).base());
```

3) `C++11` way (2)

```
std::advance(it, 1);
str.erase(it.base());
```

In all cases, `str == "5.095.9"`. Why? Because as I see it, `str` should be `5.9`, but it isn't...

My best guess is that I am doing something wrong with the backwards iterators, because if you split the string: `5.09 | 5.9`, the first value has still the in-between `'0'`, but not the last ones. The second value is actually the `std::string` I expected.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the documentation of `std::remove_if` very carefully, and think about the range you are manipulating.

Comment: i never used backward iterators, but my naive guess would be that you have to use them like this : `std::remove_if(str.rend(), str.rbegin(), [](char value)`

Comment: @KerrekSB ups, did I spoil him the exercise of rtfm ?

Comment: @tobi303 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator - here's RTFM for you :D

Comment: What about using `str.find_last_not_of('0')` to find the last non-zero digit.

Comment: Why start from the back if you're removing all the `0`s, anyway?

Comment: @KerrekSB ooh, I see my error ;) Thanks a lot, although my error was in the `erase` logic :)

Comment: @BoPersson I guess I could use that. Thanks

Comment: @LogicStuff my example gives a good reason: removing every unimportant `0` from a `double` converted into a `std::string`, but only the last ones (i.e. `5.09000000` -> `5.09`)

Comment: @Rakete1111 but your question says "...trying to remove every '0'..."

Comment: @tobi303 yes, I know, I don't want to overcomplicate things ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made 2 errors in my approach:

- `erase` called with only 1 iterator removes the element the iterator is pointing at, not from the iterator to the end (as I falsely assumed)

So `str.erase(std::next(it).base(), str.end());` - this is still wrong, continue reading ;)

- As @KerrekSB pointed out, I didn't read [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) carefully enough: Because I am using `std::reverse_iterator`, the elements get pushed back to the **front**! So, as `it` points to the new end iterator (which is BTW **before** the not-removed elements), I have to delete the range from the beginning (`str.begin()`) to `it.base()`.

---

**TL;DR**

The new working version is: `str.erase(str.begin(), it.base());`