# How to erase element with a reverse iterator from a `std::set`?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

Facing issue with deletion of last element in set :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
set < pair <int,int > > a;
a.insert(make_pair(2,3)); 
auto it = a.rbegin();
a.erase(it.base()); // for deleting last element in set
cout << a.size() << endl;
return 0; 
}
```

Getting the **runtime issue**, Also have tried with **auto**, **Iterator** and **Const iterator**, it's not working.Is there any other way to erase an element from a set ?

Edit :  How can I delete a Particular element based on iterator reference ?
if i do like :

`auto it=a.begin();
a.erase(it); Here it = reference to the element for deletion`

it doesn't work.Any other way to delete based on iterator reference ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call erase with a reverse iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any other way to erase an element from a set ?

```
a.erase(std::prev(std::end(a)));
```

---

> Can you tell me,whats problem with my code ?

`itr.base()` where `itr == a.begin()` is equivalent to `a.end()`. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base

Erasing a past-the-end iterator is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Thanks ,but Can you tell me,whats problem with my code ?

Comment: I told you - your `.base()` call basically returns `a.end()`. You're then erasing a past-the-end iterator, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Okay i got it but if I pass directly, "a.erase(it)" then also doesn't work ? even though i am passing reference for a element that needs to be deleted.