# Implementing erase() for a custom std::map iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

I have written a class to wrap around an `std::map`, along with an iterator class to allow controlling accessing the `map`'s key:

```
#include <map>

class Container
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
        using map = std::map < int, int >;
        map::const_iterator _iter;

    public:
        iterator() {}
        iterator(map::iterator iter) :_iter(iter) {}
        iterator(map::const_iterator iter) :_iter(iter) {}
        iterator(const iterator& b) :_iter(b._iter) {}

        iterator& operator=(const iterator& b)
        {
            _iter = b._iter;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator& operator++()
        {
            ++_iter;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator++(int)
        {
            return iterator(_iter++);
        }

        const map::key_type first()
        {
            return std::abs(_iter->first);
        }

        const int second()
        {
            return _iter->second;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& b)
        {
            return _iter == b._iter;
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& b)
        {
            return _iter != b._iter;
        }
    };

    void insert(int key, int value)
    {
        _map[-key] = value;  // Key is modified from user, hence need for wrapper
    }

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(_map.begin());
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(_map.end());
    }

    iterator find(int key)
    {
        return iterator(_map.find(key));
    }

    iterator erase(iterator iter)
    {
        return iterator(_map.erase(iter));
    }

private:

    std::map<int, int> _map;
};
```

My required operations are:

- Iterating
- Finding
- Erasing
- Getting key
- Getting value

I would like usage to be like:

```
int main()
{
    Container o;
    o.insert(-1, 100);
    o.insert(-2, 200);
    o.insert(-3, 300);
    o.insert(-4, 300);

    for (Container::iterator i = o.begin(); i != o.end();)
    {
        if (i.first() == -2)
        {
            std::cout << i.first() << " " << i.second() << std::endl;
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            i = o.erase(i);
        }
    }
}
```

so that I can erase elements and continue iterating.

However, I am struggling to implement the container's `erase()` method because the input is my custom `iterator` type, not the map's `key_type`.

Comment: Why do all this wrapping?  Why not just write a free function so you can say `insert(o, -1, 100)` and use the map class as-is?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Because I am modifying how the key is stored and the user is not aware of this, so I need to prevent them from having direct access. I will return the unmodified key when they call iterator.first().

Comment: Your `Container::iterator` contains a `map<int, int>::iterator`, pass that to `map::erase`. Why is `Container::iterator` default constructible? As the other comment says, this wrapper seems unnecessary.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the motivation is?  Your example does not do what you say--it stores the key unchanged.

Comment: @Praetorian I used example custom iterator code I found on SO. Have explained in previous comment the need for this class.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I originally wanted to have two std::maps, one I iterate backwards, the other forwards, using the same code. However, map.erase() doesn't work nicely with reverse_iterators, so I had the idea to store the keys in their negated form, which would allow me to iterate forwards, with the effect of iterating backwards. I need to ensure the user never retrieves the negated key, hence I need to wrap the map.

Comment: Have you seen this question about how to erase a reverse_iterator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator - again you can just write a simple free function like `erase(map, reverse_iterator)` to solve your real problem.

Comment: @user997112 No need to negate the key, you can use the opposite ordering relation (which is not the negation). Bonus, that works on keys that don't have an opposite.

Comment: @curiousguy assume you mean constructing using std::greater?

Comment: @user997112 Yes `greater` or another inverted relation. The point is that it's very easy to forget to negate a number at some point in the code, but when you have chosen an ordering relation for a container, you don't need to do anything more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare class `Container` as friend class of `Iterator`, and access the `_iter` in `erase` function.

```
class iterator
{
    friend class Container;
    //...
}

iterator Container::erase(iterator iter)
{
    return iterator(_map.erase(iter._iter));
}
```