# Erasing element from a vector – rbegin() vs begin()

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase, reverse-iterator

I'm trying to solve a problem in C++, a part of which requires me to erase elements from a vector using the `rbegin()` member function. However, the compiler throws an error every time I write the below-mentioned code. What's wrong here?

```
int main() {

    int a = 1, b = 2;

    vector<int> V = {a, b};

    auto it = V.rbegin();
    V.erase(it);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: ERROR:]

It compiles just fine, however, if I access the same element using the `begin()` member function. The code below works fine.

```
int main() {

    int a = 1, b = 2;

    vector<int> V = {a, b};

    auto it = V.begin()+1;
    V.erase(it);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you receive? It should explain the issue immediately. Specifically, I don't believe there is a `vector::erase` overload that accepts a `reverse_iterator` - only one that accepts an `iterator`.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). You will see that `erase` only accepts `const_iterator` since c++11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call erase with a reverse iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator)

Comment: Thanks Churill. Didn't know  this stuff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) overload for `reverse_iterator`. However, you can obtain the corresponding `iterator` from a `reverse_iterator` by calling its `base()` member function:

```
auto rit = V.rbegin();
auto it = rit.base();
V.erase(it);
```

This code does compile but results in *undefined behavior* because the `iterator` counterpart of `rbegin()` corresponds to `end()`. From [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) documentation:

```
iterator erase(const_iterator pos);
```

> The iterator `pos` must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus **the `end()` iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for `pos`**.

---

`rbegin().base()` returns `end()`, not `end() - 1`. Nevertheless, you can advance `rbegin()` by one if you want a dereferencable iterator:

```
auto it = (std::next(rit)).base();
```